# Toggle function on radio button click in bootstrap and angular 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4. I have this Bootstrap button group:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="usecase" name="options" id="option1" [value]="customer"> Kundenzuordnung
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="usecase" name="options" id="option2" [value]="stock"> Lagerware
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="usecase" name="options" id="option3" [value]="internalUse"> Interne Verwendung
    </label>
</div>
```

I want a function to be called when a button is selected and I have tried all of the following methods/properties below:

- `(click)`
- `onclick`
- `onkeydown`
- `ng-change`
- `(ngModelChange)`
- left out value field

How can I call my function `formChange(0)` when the user selects a button?

Comment: What another option ?

Comment: ? i dont understand your question

Comment: You said "how can i call my function formChange(0), when the user selects another option". What another option?

Comment: `(ngModelChange)="myFunction($event)"` should work.

Comment: nope, it doesn't :/

Comment: using `(click)="anotherFunction(0)"` on each input it will resolve your problem. it is working for me..just send different id's from each input

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz? If `[(ngModel)]` works, I don't see how `(ngModelChange)` would not be triggered. Maybe you could show how you tried it exactly. Or see if you have errors in the console when you select an item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it was so easy... i had to add the `(click)` function to the label, not to the input.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one , I think this will work.**

```
 <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(form.value)">

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="customer" ngModel> Kundenzuordnung
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="stock" ngModel> Lagerware
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="internalUse" ngModel> Interne Verwendung
        </label>
    </div>

 </form>
```